# SAP CX - HYBRIS : Configure the input to only show hours - defaulttime

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

I added a new attribute at the a section in the backoffice.
I added a date time attribute

```
                <editorArea:attribute qualifier="DateCutOffTime" defaultEditor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttime">
                        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
                            <editorArea:name>timeFormat</editorArea:name>    
                            <editorArea:value>short</editorArea:value>
                        </editorArea:editor-parameter>
                        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
                            <editorArea:name>timeZoneReadOnly</editorArea:name>
                            <editorArea:value>false</editorArea:value>  
                        </editorArea:editor-parameter>
                        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
                             <editorArea:name>selectedTimeZone</editorArea:name>
                             <editorArea:value>GMT+01:00</editorArea:value>
                        </editorArea:editor-parameter>
                        <editorArea:editor-parameter>
                             <editorArea:name>displayedTimeZones</editorArea:name>
                             <editorArea:value>GMT-12:00,GMT-11:00,GMT-10:00,GMT-09:30,GMT-09:00,GMT-08:00,GMT-07:00,GMT-06:00,GMT-05:00,GMT-04:30,GMT-04:00,GMT-03:30,GMT-03:00,GMT-02:00,GMT-01:00,GMT+00:00,GMT+01:00,GMT+02:00,GMT+03:00,GMT+03:30,GMT+04:00,GMT+04:30,GMT+05:00,GMT+05:30,GMT+05:45,GMT+06:00,GMT+06:30,GMT+07:00,GMT+08:00,GMT+08:30,GMT+08:45,GMT+09:00,GMT+09:30,GMT+10:00,GMT+10:30,GMT+11:00,GMT+12:00,GMT+12:45,GMT+13:00,GMT+14:00</editorArea:value>
                        </editorArea:editor-parameter>
                    </editorArea:attribute>
```

But i have a display with a calendar

[image]

I want to display a component just with the time to choose and timezone or only show hours.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mix 2 different types of configuration

This line is wrong:

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="DateCutOffTime" defaultEditor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttime">
```

You want to use an editor for a specific property (qualifier). For that, you need to write the header with `editor` instead of `defaultEditor`. If you look at the correspondig xsd validation, you will notice that defaultEditor is not a valid config option. Change this to `editor`, and it should work. (assuming DateCutoffTime is a property and not a type on one of your objects, if it's a type, look at the 2nd part of the answer)

```
<editorArea:attribute qualifier="DateCutOffTime" editor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttime">
```

corresponding xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="attribute">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="abstractPositioned">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="editor-parameter" type="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute name="qualifier" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute name="visible" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="true"/>
                <xs:attribute name="readonly" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
                <xs:attribute name="editor" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute name="merge-mode" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
                <xs:attribute name="description" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
```

(For completion)

As far as I'm aware, defaultEditor is only ever used to define a default editor for a **type**. Then you need to specify the type for which you want to create a default editor. This also needs to be placed in a .zul file, and not in the regular backoffice config files.

```
<editor id="textEditor" type="java.lang.String" defaultEditor="com.hybris.cockpitng.editor.defaulttext"/>
```